# What are the cases where one decide the presence of a specific organism in bacteriological clinical samples based on direct Gram stain?

Tags: bacteria, microbiology

### Background information

Direct microscopic examination (or Direct smear) typically refer to microscopic examination of a specimen before any culture or inoculation is performed.

### Question

While screening for a specific bacterial organism in a clinical sample, what are the cases where it's right (or wrong) to rule out the presence of such an organism in the sample, based on the absence of the organism's cell morphotype in the smear?

### Prior research

One case where it's wrong to do such a ruling out is direct Gram stains performed on blood samples, due to the low organism density in most blood samples. *****

> ***** (2016). Staining Procedures. In Clinical Microbiology Procedures
> Handbook, A.L. Leber (Ed.).
> https://doi.org/10.1128/9781555818814.ch3.2.1